# URL error in HTTP endpoint for QAComplete

Tags: web-services, rest, wsdl, endpoint

I am trying to access the `endpoint` and `WSDL` for QAComplete on company premises using the company server url. Unfortunately I am receiving a `url error`. Please see the example below, have I missed something obvious?

Example:

```
Endpoint: http://yourserver/psws/psws.asmx
```

Company server:

```
Endpoint: http://app2.qacomplete.smartbear.com/Common/psws/psws.asmx
```

Best regards,
AmiK

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own query. Was using the wrong URL.

Correct REST API address for SaaS clients is https://qacomplete.smartbear.com/rest-api/service